# Unable to match an mysql string response in freeradius

Tags: mysql, freeradius

I using freeradius 2.2.8 and mysql for sending our coa/disconnect messages via freeradius when a bandwidth quota is hit. That part of the code is working great. Unfortunately for me the coa/disconnect message is sent out even though an Accounting Stop is sent out by the NAS. In order to prevent that from happening I am putting a condition where in I pull the acct termination cause from mysql radacct table and compare it against some strings.

Under accounting,

```
update control {
....
Tmp-String-0 := "%{sql:SELECT acctterminatecause AS Terminate FROM radacct WHERE radacct.username='%{User-Name}' AND radacct.acctsessionid='%{Acct-Session-Id}'}}"

 ***if ("%{control:Tmp-String-0}" != "User-Request")***{
      if (("%{control:Tmp-Integer-0}" > "%{control:Tmp-Integer-2}") || ("%{control:Tmp-Integer-1}" > "%{control:Tmp-Integer-3}")){
        if ("%{control:coa_dm}" == "coa"){
            update coa {
               User-Name = "%{User-Name}"
               Acct-Session-Id = "%{Acct-Session-Id}"
               NAS-IP-Address = "%{NAS-IP-Address}"
               #Filter-Id = "UN-AUTHORIZED-PROFILE"
               Framed-IP-Address = "%{Framed-IP-Address}"
               Session-Timeout = 10
            }
         }
        if ("%{control:coa_dm}" == "dm"){
            update disconnect {
                User-Name = "%{User-Name}"
                NAS-IP-Address = "%{NAS-IP-Address}"
            }
         }

}
}
```

As per the freeradius debug logs we can see that the string should be a match and the program should avoid the inside if conditions. Unfortunately that is not the case and the 1st IF condition always returns true.

```
***Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info:        expand: SELECT acctterminatecause  AS Terminate FROM radacct WHERE radacct.username='%{User-Name}' AND radacct.acctsessionid='%{Acct-Session-Id}' -> SELECT acctterminatecause AS Terminate FROM radacct WHERE radacct.username='kiranc' AND radacct.acctsessionid='5AFD71CB-3FE1C000'
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Debug: rlm_sql (sql): Reserving sql socket id: 16
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info: sql_xlat finished
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Debug: rlm_sql (sql): Released sql socket id: 16
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info:        expand: %{sql:SELECT acctterminatecause AS Terminate FROM radacct WHERE radacct.username='%{User-Name}' AND radacct.acctsessionid='%{Acct-Session-Id}'}} -> User-Request}
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info: ++} # update control = noop
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info: ++? if ("%{control:Tmp-String-0}" != "User-Request")
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info:        expand: %{control:Tmp-String-0} -> User-Request}
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info: ? Evaluating ("%{control:Tmp-String-0}" != "User-Request") -> TRUE***
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info: ++? if ("%{control:Tmp-String-0}" != "User-Request") -> TRUE
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info: ++if ("%{control:Tmp-String-0}" != "User-Request") {
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info: +++? if (("%{control:Tmp-Integer-0}" > "%{control:Tmp-Integer-2}") || ("%{control:Tmp-Integer-1}" > "%{control:Tmp-Integer-3}"))
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info:        expand: %{control:Tmp-Integer-0} -> 3169
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info:        expand: %{control:Tmp-Integer-2} -> 25000000
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info: ?? Evaluating ("%{control:Tmp-Integer-0}" > "%{control:Tmp-Integer-2}") -> FALSE
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info:        expand: %{control:Tmp-Integer-1} -> 13402
Thu May 17 17:43:41 2018 : Info:        expand: %{control:Tmp-Integer-3} -> 50000000
```

I tried the single quotes, double quotes using the & instead of %, but to no avail. The other conditions are met correctly when hit as they are returned as integers.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I had got it working. Instead of comparing using Tmp-String-0 variable I just used the actual radius attribute name and got it working.

```
if (("%{Acct-Terminate-Cause}" != "User-Request")
```

Thank you for the help.